# Input or Request are always empty in controllers

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need some help on a topic that is making me crazy on Laravel 5.2

I have the following routes.php, which I have reduced to the minimum :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
* Category Page
*/
Route::get('/category/test/', function()
    {
        dd("I'm in !");
        dd(Input::all());

        $page = Input::get('page');

        if(isset($page)){
            dd($page);
        }
    }
```

When I call the following url : http://192.168.99.100/category/test?page=55, I would expect to get the parameter page in Input or Request but however it is always empty. The following code just displays "I'm in !" but nothing else.

Can you help me understanding what is wrong in here ? I previously used controllers and Request parameters but it was also empty, thus this simple test. Note that post requests are working fine.

Thanks !

Comment: Add on your function : function(Request $request) and replace dd ($request->input('page'); let me know if it work, if it request class Request add the class request.

Comment: $page = $request->input('page');

Comment: I changed to : 

Route::get('/category/test/',  function(Request $request)
        {
            dd("I'm in !");
            dd ($request->input('page'));
            dd ($request->all());
        }

and still have the same result .... only "I'm in !" displayed

Comment: Try to change this : if(!empty($page)){dd($page);}

Comment: Same behavior - seems all the parameters are dropped before ..

Comment: If i display this : print_r ($request->fullUrl());

I can see the url with the parameters removed

Comment: Consider to change url and route: Route::get('/category/test/{page}', function($page) { dd("I'm in !"); dd ($page);  }  URL WILL BE LIKE THIS: http://192.168.99.100/category/test/55

Comment: This is definitely working but .. it's not the behavior I want ..

Comment: http://192.168.99.100/category/test?page={page} but I don't if it is the best way, usually request work fine, can you post the link that generate this url? Did you use route blade?

Comment: Actually I enter this url manually to test - but request should work .. I don't understand why the parameters are dropped. I tried to remove all the plugins but no luck ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it out !

That was a problem in my nginx configuration, that prevented php variable QUERY_STRING to be correctly set up and Laravel is basing on this variable to retrieve the data.

For more information, see https://serverfault.com/questions/231578/nginx-php-fpm-where-are-my-get-params/362924#362924

Thaks for your answers anyway !

Answer (score 1):

You can use both , actually there is no error in your code except if you missed the use statement for `Input` facade.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
* Category Page
*/
Route::get('/category/test/', function()
    {

        dd(Input::all());
        dd("I'm in !");

        $page = Input::get('page');

        if(isset($page)){
            dd($page);
        }
    }
```

So question is why you are getting nothing! because the route is GET request so if you post/update/patch anything to it you will get methodNotAllowed exception. Now just goto your browser and type `http://whateverdomain/category/test/?page=atiq&have=fun` and yes now there is something.........

```
Route::get('/category/test/', function(Request $request)
    {
         $input=$request->All();
         dd($input);

        $page = request->get('page');

        if(isset($page)){
            dd($page, request->get('have'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't told function to expect request

it shall be

```
Route::get('/category/test/', function(Request $Request)
    {
         $input=$Request->All();
         dd($input);
            // usage $input['query'];
        $page = Input::get('page');

        if(isset($page)){
            dd($page);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Request is not necessary as a function parameter to call Input::get
My issue was due no nginx configuration, see my answer